# Why the program crashes?

Tags: c++, struct

This code compiles correctly but crashes at start. can you tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct test{
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    test* xyz;

    xyz->a = 5;

    cout<< xyz->a;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior? Using unitialized pointer, so pointing to somewhere and most likely not what you want

Comment: *This code compiles correctly but crashes at start.*  --  Just because your program compiles correctly doesn't mean it will automatically run correctly.

Comment: thanks for the knowlwdge @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xyz is only a pointer, but it doesn't points to anything. You have to instantiate it before using its values. You basically have two options:

1. Instantiate xyz by creating a new object of test on the heap.

   ```
   //generate new test object. xyz represents a pointer to an object of type test.
   test* xyz = new test();

   //perform operations on xyz

   //deletes xyz from the heap
   delete xyz;
   ```
2. Create a test object on the stack, without using pointers syntax.

   ```
   //defines xyz as an object of class test (instead of a pointer to a test object).
   test xyz;

   //perform operations on xyz, no need to delete it this time
   ```

I encourage you to read more about pointers in C++.
You can start from the following video:
 [Introduction to Pointers in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0aE-w61Cb8)

Good luck!